# Rectangles created from java.awt.Graphics dissapear shortly after window is launched

Tags: java, swing

**Overview:** I'm making a chess game using Swing (Java) and while making the checkered-board pattern, I've run into an issue where the rectangles that I created with `drawRect` disappear shortly after the window is launched.

This problem does not occur when the rectangles I created are not in a `for` loop, though I am not sure as to why.

```java
public class Main extends JPanel {
    
    private static JFrame frame;
    private static Container contentPanel;
    private int rectX = 0;
    private int rectY = 0;
    
    // draw game textures
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        // draw chess board
        for (int i = 1; i <= 64; i++) {
            
            // light square
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                g.drawRect(rectX, rectY, 100, 100);
                rectX += 100;
            }
            // dark square
            else {
                g.fillRect(rectX, rectY, 100, 100);
                rectX += 100;
            }
            
            // check if the row has ended
            if (i % 8 == 0 && i != 0) {
                rectX = 0;
                rectY += 100;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // define preferred size
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 800);
    }
    
    // create GUI
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Main main = new Main();
        
        frame = new JFrame("Java Chess V1.0");
        contentPanel = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPanel.add(main);
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've tried making individual rectangles instead of using a `for` loop, which works, but I'd rather not have 64 lines of `g.drawRect(...)` if possible.

Comment: How do you even see the drawn rectangles since they are all surrounded by filled rectangles of the same color? The only place you'll see an edge is at the edge of the entire board.

Comment: Myself, I wouldn't even draw the grid as you're doing but rather would use a grid of JPanels placed in a GridLayout. My reasoning is that I want the chess square to be able to hold a chess piece (probably a JLabel with an image icon), and a JPanel would work perfectly for this.

Comment: `private int rectX = 0;     private int rectY = 0;` Those variables are used in the painting method and should be initialized in the painting method, otherwise they never reset to 0, the next time the panel is painted. So the panel simply gets cleared by the super.paintComponent(...) statement. Also, you should not be using static variables. Your painting panel should not need to reference the frame directly.

Comment: [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21432607/522444)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's what I was thinking of doing instead. I'll try doing that instead, and post an update when done.

Comment: `private static JFrame frame; private static Container contentPanel;` are code smells and generally a bad idea

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *How do you even see the drawn rectangle* - the code uses a `drawRect(...)` and `fillRect(...)`. So the background of the drawRect will be the background of the panel. Tricky, but the painting logic is still wrong (it paints columns of the same colour not alternating squares).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a *[GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridLayout.html)* to create the pattern.

```java
public class Main extends JPanel {

    private static JFrame frame;
    private static Container contentPanel;

    Main() {
        draw();
    }

    // draw game textures
    private void draw() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        double w = getPreferredSize().getWidth(),
               h = getPreferredSize().getHeight();
        Dimension d = new Dimension((int) (w / 8), (int) (h / 8));
        Color cb = Color.black, cw = Color.white;
        boolean b = true;
        JLabel label;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8 * 8; i++) {
            label = new JLabel();
            label.setPreferredSize(d);
            b = i % 8 == 0 == b;
            label.setBackground(b ? cb : cw);
            label.setOpaque(true);
            add(label);
        }
    }

    // define preferred size
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 800);
    }

    // create GUI
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Main main = new Main();

        frame = new JFrame("Java Chess V1.0");
        contentPanel = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPanel.add(main);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is the *Java* tutorial on *GridLayout*.

- *[How to Use GridLayout (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With Swing > Laying Out Components Within a Container)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)*.

Answer (score 0):

Solution suggested by [@Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels)

I took some personal liberties in formatting the code, but this idea worked. I have ActionListener there for when I add the game's functionality.

```java
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    
    private static final int ranks = 8;
    private static final int files = ranks;
    private static final Dimension squareSize = new Dimension(80, 80);
    private static final Color lightSquareColor = Color.gray;
    private static final Color darkSquareColor = Color.black;
    
    private static List<JPanel> boardSquares = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
    
    private JPanel chessBoard = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ranks, files));
    
    public Main() {
        // create ranks/files
        for (int rank = 0; rank < ranks; rank++) {
            for (int file = 0; file < files; file++) {
                // create a square and set its size/color
                JPanel square = new JPanel();
                square.setPreferredSize(squareSize);
                Color squareColor = (rank % 2 == file % 2) ? lightSquareColor : darkSquareColor;
                square.setBackground(squareColor);
                // add square to the chess board and to the list of squares for game functionality purposes
                chessBoard.add(square);
                boardSquares.add(square);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void createGrid() {
        // define layout for main panel
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        
        // left-side rank labels
        gbConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gbConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gbConstraints.gridwidth = 1;
        gbConstraints.gridheight = 1;
        gbConstraints.weightx = 0.0;
        gbConstraints.weighty = 0.0;
        gbConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10);
        add(createRankPanel(), gbConstraints);
        
        // right-size rank labels
        gbConstraints.gridx = 2;
        gbConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        add(createRankPanel(), gbConstraints);
        
        // top file labels
        gbConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gbConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gbConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        gbConstraints.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 0);
        add(createFilePanel(), gbConstraints);
        
        // bottom file labels
        gbConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gbConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        add(createFilePanel(), gbConstraints);
        
        // the chess board itself
        gbConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gbConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gbConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0 ,0);
        add(chessBoard, gbConstraints);
    }
    
    // creates a files panel (for labeling) and returns the panel
    private JPanel createFilePanel() {
        JPanel filePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
        for (int i = 0; i < files; i++) {
            // set current letter by increasing its ASCII value
            char fileLetter = (char) ('A' + i);
            filePanel.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(fileLetter), SwingConstants.CENTER));
        }
        return filePanel;
    }
    
    // creates a ranks panel (for labeling) and returns the panel
    private JPanel createRankPanel() {
        JPanel rankPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
        for (int i = 0; i < ranks; i++) {
            // count down rather than up
            int currentRow = ranks - i;
            rankPanel.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(currentRow)));
        }
        return rankPanel;
    }

    // method to start app
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        // calls
        Main mainPanel = new Main();
        mainPanel.createGrid();
        
        // make and configure window
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Chess v1.0");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    // start the app
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be an alternative approach but it doesn't solve the problem for your original question which was about custom painting, which you are doing incorrectly. The solution to your original question has been given in the comments.